# How to change value of a primary key when its a foreign key reference in another table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a table user_type and user_type_id is the primary key of that table and I have another table user_details where user_type_id is a reference of the foreign key.

I want to change the id value of the user_type_id column.

Answer (score 0):

First update `user_details` to set the foreign key column to NULL for the rows that depend on the primary key, then update `user_type`, then change the rows in `user_details` to the updated value.

You can make this easier in two ways:

1. define the foreign key with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`, then this happens automatically
2. define the foreign key as `DEFERRABLE`, the you can defer the check to the end of the transaction